# Using relay for switching DC 24V supply

Tags: relay

Can a relay be used for switching DC circuits or is exclusively for switching AC devices?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! What does the datasheet say?

Answer (score 1):

For both, **provided they stay within the voltage and current ratings**.

Most times, there is a difference between the DC ratings and the AC ratings of a relay.
For DC applications you should **never** assume/apply AC ratings.
When no DC ratings are given, don't use the relay for DC applications.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the relay specification, you need to look at the marking or its datasheet, it could be both of them or either one of them. Ideally, it can be used for switching both DC and AC because when the coil is energized its metal contact touch each others, it can be seen as passive resistive component with very small resistance, just like lamp switch on your wall. But in reality, the relay must be designed in such a way that it will be operate as reliably as possible. Also the complexity to achieve it may be lessen in order to achieve 
a low cost relay that only focuses on one mode.

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay

Comment: @SamGibson Okay done, at first, I misunderstood that the OP could be asking on practical condition, my answer on relay is at ideal condition so I illustrated as a simple lamp switch, I forgot that the practical one is different. Thank you for the critics. Is there anything else to make my answer better?